# click to javascript button with python

Tags: python

I want write a bot for steam trade. But i cant found example for it with python. I think if i can click a button with python i can do it. Is it true?
If i can click "Accept Trade" button its fine.

I can scrap source with beautifulsoup library but I couldn't any user operation with it.

Here is accept button's source code:

```
<div id="trade_confirmbtn" class="trade_confirmbtn ellipsis" onclick="ConfirmTradeOffer();">
```

And here is trade page link hierarchy:

```
https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/{{tradeid}}/
```

I have not a code yet. Thank you!

Comment: You either automate a browser that can execute JavaScript or you check what the JavaScript function does and then send the request from your python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) is a python module that can interact with web-page resources, so that's an easy way to execute JavaScript code from within Python.